# Collection undefined when trying to create a relationship

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

I'm trying to create a very basic relationship in Meteor using `aldeed:collection2`.

I have two collections; `Blogs` and `Posts`. Each post should belong to one blog, so I've added `blog` of type `Blogs` to my `Posts` schema.

```
Blogs = new Mongo.Collection('blogs');
BlogsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  ...
});
Blogs.attachSchema(BlogsSchema);
```

---

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');
PostsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  blog: {
    type: Blogs
  },
  ...
});
Posts.attachSchema(PostsSchema);
```

This should work, however, as soon as Meteor restarts, I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: Blogs is not defined at collections/Posts.js

How do I solve this? If I understand it correctly, there is a problem with the collections being in separate files. However, if I place my Blogs.js deeper (Meteor loads deeper files first), I get this:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: I wonder if [relationships](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2/blob/master/RELATIONSHIPS.md) is a fully implemented feature yet. The doc hasn't been updated in a long while.

Comment: I've been reading through [this issue](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2/issues/246). Apparently, the file you linked is only a concept, not an actual implementation. The only way to create a relationship is to use the `_id` and then join manually.

Comment: Manually embedding documents on client-side seems to be the go-to option as only database cursors are reactive on server-side. Refer [this](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation on [Relationships](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2/blob/master/RELATIONSHIPS.md) for meteor-collections2 at GitHub.

Note how in the Colors collection the reference to the Cars collection is enclosed in square brackets:

```
cars: {
  type: [Cars],
```

Maybe the square brackets are the key to solving this issue for you.

Comment: Square brackets would imply an array of Blogs, which would mean that each post has multiple Blogs and that is not what I'm trying to achieve. I've read through the documentation, and you can see it also states that one car has 0 or 1 color, using `type: Colors`.

Comment: Maybe so, but there can always be an array with only one object in it. I set up a new meteor project, and added two files (blog.js and post.js) to it with the code you have in your question above. The only change I made was to add square brackets ( `type: [Blogs]` ) to PostsSchema and meteor started up without any errors.

Comment: I suppose I could turn the relationship around and have Blogs have multiple Posts. However, I've decided to only store the Blog `_id` in posts and then join the relationship manually. I've commented on my question with a bit more info.